# Jagged edges using a toon shader and Evee

Tags: materials, shaders

I am trying to create a cartoon style render using evee with light reflections on the material (wich is suposed to be metal). I tried everything like subdividing, auto smooth, changing shadow resolution... Nothing seems to work.

My node look like that ( the part with colors really close together is to make the reflections apear)

If anyone has an anwser to this problem, it could help me a lot, thanks :)

[image: jagged edges]

[image: color ramp node]

Comment: Can you show the rest of your node tree?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that :  https://imgur.com/a/nxxP2VW

Comment: Try making the light source really really small by scaling it.